# Leer o Recibir información SOAP-XML con Laravel

Tags: laravel, xml, soap, restful

Hola eh estado trabajando en una Restful API con Laravel, se muy bien como consumir servicios soap enviar peticiones y leer respuestas etc, pero mi pregunta es:

Un Cliente SOAP puede consumir mi API Laravel?

Un Externo manda regularmente información hacia nuestros sistemas, la cual procesamos y guardamos. Pero ellos mandan su información usando SOAP y XML desde vb6, y no estoy seguro si Laravel puede recibir/leer esa petición en un endpoint y como la debería leer, o si esto es posible?

de antemano gracias